# 16.04 - Use NTP server assigned by DHCP

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, dhcp, ntp

I'm trying to have Ubuntu use the NTP server IP's that my local firewall provides it via DHCP, but `timedatectl` seems insistent on using its own `[alphyn/chilipepper/golem].canonical.com` servers. No way seems to exist for changing NTP servers with `timedatectl`, and I don't want to use `ntp` because `timedatectl` is supposed to have completely replaced and deprecated it.

1. How can I have Ubuntu use the DHCP-provided NTP server IP? (**Ideal**)

--OR--

2. How can I change the default NTP server that `timedatectl` calls out to? (would suffice)

Comment: To specify an NTP server for the client to use, use `option 42 [ip-address]` in your DHCP options.

Comment: Will my DHCP server forward its NTP configuration to its clients if I specify the DHCP server's IP address in the clients' NTP config? If not, will my clients at least sync their time with my DHCP server? I'm not using Ubuntu as DHCP/NTP server in this environment btw

Comment: Seems to be handled by systemd-timesyncd.service systemd unit. Did you check editing [`/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-timesyncd)?